# error creating oozie database schema

Tags: hadoop, installation, bigdata, cloudera, oozie

I'm trying to setup oozie (cdh4) using RPM on RHEL5. When I run the command to setup schemas in mysql database using `sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh create -run` it gives me an error stating "No such file or directory". You can view the logs for the same [here](http://pastebin.com/2PMXa9Vv).

While if I try to run the command to just create scripts using `sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie-create.sql` it gives me an error stating " unable to connect to database". You can view the logs for the same [here](http://pastebin.com/nhqffu6C).

I am following [cdh4 installation site for oozie](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_17_6.html).

Please help me figure out the possible errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do all of the Temp directories exist (`/var/lib/oozie`), and does the oozie user have permissions to write / execute that folder?

Comment: Hi @Chris! Thank you for trying to help me here. [Here](http://pastebin.com/0PKtHJ7n) is the list of files I have in the directory you mentioned. The directory you mentioned and its contents belong to oozie user and group and I'm tryin to run it using the same user, as mentioned in the above guide.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having some sort of permissions issue when trying to create the init sql file. The code for oozie cdh4 where the error emanates from is [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.oozie/oozie-tools/3.3.0-cdh4.2.0/org/apache/oozie/tools/OozieDBCLI.java#OozieDBCLI):

```
String sqlFile = (commandLine.hasOption(SQL_FILE_OPT))
      ? commandLine.getOptionValue(SQL_FILE_OPT)
      : File.createTempFile("ooziedb-", ".sql").getAbsolutePath();
```

So you could try and pass in the SQL_FILE_OPT and name a path that you know exists, and the user oozie can write too. You've already done in your second command line, but i would fully qualify the path to the sql file, and put it somewhere where you know the oozie you can write to (/tmp, which should in reality be where File.createTempFile(..) creates the file).

```
sudo -u oozie touch /tmp/oozie-create.sql
sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/ooziedb.sh create \
    -sqlfile /tmp/oozie-create.sql
```

Comment: Hi @Chris! I tried this way too but still no luck. I somehow believe that my java home has some issues, however when I do an echo it points to the right path. Is there any way I can explicitly override the path by passing it as an arguement ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my db oozie was emptly, so I drop the db, and create it again! 
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ******

mysql> create database oozie;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>  grant all privileges on oozie.* to 'oozie'@'localhost' identified by 'oozie';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>  grant all privileges on oozie.* to 'oozie'@'%' identified by 'oozie';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

then

Validate DB Connection
DONE
Check DB schema does not exist
DONE
Check OOZIE_SYS table does not exist
DONE
Create SQL schema
DONE
Create OOZIE_SYS table
DONE
Set MySQL MEDIUMTEXT flag
DONE

Oozie DB has been created for Oozie version '3.3.2-cdh4.7.0'